# Inheriting from a F# generative type provider provided type

Tags: inheritance, f#, type-providers

I have this basic generative F# type provider

```
[<TypeProvider>]
type MyTypeProvider(config : TypeProviderConfig) as this = 
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces(config)

    let ns = "MyNamespace"
    let asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(config.RuntimeAssembly)

    let buildTypes (typeName:string) (args:obj[]) =
        let asm = ProvidedAssembly()
        let srvName = args.[0] :?> string
        ... omitted
        let provided = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, typeName, Some typeof<MyRuntimeType>, hideObjectMethods = true, nonNullable = true, isErased = false)
        let ctor = ProvidedConstructor([], (fun _ -> <@@ MyRuntimeType() @@>))
        provided.AddMember(ctor)
        provided
    let parameters = 
        [ ProvidedStaticParameter("Host", typeof<string>, "") ]

    let provider = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "MyProvider", Some typeof<obj>, hideObjectMethods = true, nonNullable = true, isErased = false)
    do provider.DefineStaticParameters(parameters, buildTypes)
    do this.AddNamespace(ns, [provider])

[<assembly:TypeProviderAssembly()>]
do ()
```

In a different project, I want to use the provided type not directly, but by inheriting from it:

```
type Provided = MyNamespace.MyProvider<"Host123">

type Derived() = 
    inherit Provided() //Cannot inherit a sealed type
```

However I get an error saying that the provided type is a sealed class, so it can't be inherited from.

Is this by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior in the F# Type Provider SDK.  You can see the attributes used for Provided Type Definitions in [ProvidedTypes.fs](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/blob/master/src/ProvidedTypes.fs) in the `ProvidedTypeDefinition` class (around lines 1241-1252):

```
    static let defaultAttributes isErased = 
        TypeAttributes.Public ||| 
        TypeAttributes.Class ||| 
        TypeAttributes.Sealed ||| 
        enum (if isErased then int32 TypeProviderTypeAttributes.IsErased else 0)
```

You can override this by explicitly passing the `TypeAttributes` for the fifth parameter of the constructor (you'll have to use the constructor that takes all the parameters).  Picking up after your `... omitted` section, that would look something like this:

```
let derivableClassAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class

let provided = 
    ProvidedTypeDefinition(false, 
                           TypeContainer.Namespace (K asm,ns), 
                           typeName, 
                           K (Some typeof<MyRuntimeType>), 
                           derivableClassAttributes, 
                           K None, 
                           [], 
                           None, 
                           None, 
                           K [||], 
                           true, 
                           true)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. the primary constructor is not recognized by the compiler (because the fsi file doesn't declare it i guess). Also, for example, the second parameter uses the type TypeContainer, which is declared with the RequireQualifiedAccessAttribute, so I should use the full name 'ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.TypeContainer.Namespace (K asm,ns)' but even that is not recognized by the compiler (for the same reason I think). Hence the solution you suggested is technically correct, but can't be used without tweaking the SDK sources